# Default method of `io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver` faile org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver` is missing

Tags: appium, appium-android

I'm new in mobile testing and try to understand what I do wrong.

**I try to test my app using Appium, but I have some troubles with the installation**

First I instal

- Android Studio
- Appium Jar files for Java
- Latest Appium Client Library
- Appium Server
- Java

**Trying to build gradle from the application I receive some errors**

> Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process ...\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\java-client-6.1.0.jar
>
> Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
>
> Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
>
> Error: Default method desugaring of `io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver` failed because its super class `org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver` is missing

**My libs directory has**

- byte-buddy-1.8.15.jar
- commons-exec-1.3.jar
- guava-25.0-jre.jar
- java-client-6.1.0.jar
- okhttp-3.11.0.jar okio-1.14.0.jar

I don't use Maven or something else, and I can't add something to pom.xml

**If you have some ideas how I can resolve this problem, please, help me...**

Comment: I think `selenium java` is missing, you can try by adding it.

Comment: I already add it this 4 .jars are from selenium folder

 byte-buddy-1.8.15.jar
commons-exec-1.3.jar
java-client-6.1.0.jar
okhttp-3.11.0.jar okio-1.14.0.jar

Comment: From this link download selenium Java: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java   and add this jar also in your project

Comment: @AlImran it doesn't helps me.

Comment: @AlImran maybe you can help me solve this issue on skype call?

Comment: @СветланаДемчукова Did you find any solution for the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add environment variables for both JAVA and Android Sdk? Seems like those are missing. Add those android variables and try again.

Comment: Hi, Add all the environment variables for JAVA and for Sdk.
If I check java -v in cmd i receive the current version of java